# Stop fgets escaping '\' in C (so I can input characters in octal form)

Tags: c, command-line, ascii, fgets

My intent is to insert a character from the command line in octal form, e.g. `\064` (the char '4') and have `fgets` interpret it as the correct character the way `echo` does, rather than add an extra '\' beforehand `\\064` so that the backslash and numbers themselves are read.

My motivation for doing this is so I can input special characters that don't have keyboard equivalents and that I can't paste in, e.g. `\021` or `\035`, device control 1 and the group separator respectively.

(The characters must be input from command line; I can't alter the code).

Comment: The backslash is only an escape character in character and string literals.

Comment: So what is your question? How to input special characters in command line? If you can't change the code, then I assume this is a practical question on how to handle special characters in your shell?

Comment: Also, no input function does any kind of parsing of the input (except possible line-handling translation when opening a file in text-mode). If you want to input special characters you have to work with the terminal/command-line program.

Comment: `fgets` does not escape any characters.  Your title doesn't match what your question is asking. I'd suggest changing title to *How to convert octal sequence to character* or similar.

Comment: also, clarify whether you are expecting just "\021" on a single line, or if you for example want to convert "foo\101" to "fooA"

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not built into `fgets` (or any other function in the standard library). If you need it, you have to implement it yourself (one way to do it is calling `getc` in a loop, detecting backslashes and the following characters, and computing the octal value), or you need to find a library which can do it, and use it.

If you need to parse the the backslashes in the command-line, there may be an easier way depending which operating system and which shell you are using. For example, the following Bash command calls `./myprog` with `argv[1] = "A@B"`:

```
./myprog $'A\001B'
```